# Preencher um campo texto e este aparecer invertida, no formato yy/mm/dd hh:mm

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia pessoal, preciso achar uma forma de preencher um campo data e no momento do preenchimento o mesmo seja inserido em outro input, mas no formato americano, pois usarei esta campo para fazer um insert em um BD.
Ja iniciei alguns teste do tipo,

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var div = document.querySelector('div');

input.addEventListener('keyup', function () {

    div.innerHTML = input.value;
});
```

Sei que assim eu digito e ele ja imprimi em outro lugar, mas como juntar o metodo .split?

Comment: Qual é o formato de entrada e qual deverá ser o formato de saída?

Comment: entra formato BR e sai formato EN para insert no banco.
EX. 29/08/2018 10:24 e sai 2018-08-29 10:24

Comment: `dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii` para `yyyy/mm/dd hh:ii`? E se utilizará esse valor no *backend*, você não deveria adicioná-lo em um novo `input`? O texto dentro de uma `div` não é enviado na submissão do formulário.

Comment: dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii para yyyy/mm/dd hh:ii, isso mesmo, sim eu vou adicionalo em um novo input. o exemplo acima é só para mostrar o evento addEventListener

Comment: se estiver usando php como backend, então é melhor tratar essa data pelo php

Comment: O desenvolvimento não é em PHP.

Comment: a minha idéia, seria usar um <input type="text" hidden> para receber a data no formato que desejo.

Comment: Você pode usar o tipo date no input html, que faz todo o processo de troca. **[Leia aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/data)**

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

No `<head>` utilizei o JavaScript abaixo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dialanform = document.getElementById("dia").value;
    var ditual = dialanform.split(" ");
    var y1 = ditual[0];
    var diamod = x1.split("/");
    var y3 = diamod[2] + '-' + diamod[1] + '-' + diamod[0];
    var diatime = datalanform.split(":");
    var y1time = ditual[1]


    document.querySelector('input[name="diaslice"]').value = y3 + " " + y1time;
</script>
```

E no HTML utlizei a função `onblur="preencher_d(this)"`.

Com isso o campo `input` que precisava inverteu no formato desejado.

Answer (score 1):

Poderia fazer de uma forma mais simples com jquery, ou uma função em script.

```
<html>
    <input type="date" name="data" id="data">
</html>

<script>
//exemplo com jquery
$('#data').change(function(){ //talvez seja melhor usar o change do que o blur, onde ele só irá salvar se houver uma alteração.
        var dataReal = $(this).val(); //por pdrão o input date já ve no formato amaricano.
        var partes = dataReal.split("-"); //separa os valores pelo '-' em um array

        //exemplo 1 - separando o array em variaveis
        var dia = partes[2];
        var mes = partes[1];
        var ano = partes[0];
        var dataBr = dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano;

        //exemplo 2 - montagem direta
        var dataBr = partes[2]+"/"+partes[1]+"/"+partes[0];
        alert(dataBr);
    });
</script>
```